# Двухуровневое меню на php и mysql

Tags: меню, php, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать двухуровневое меню. Я на процедурном стиле понимаю как его сделать, а вот на ООП чет не получается. Я использую фреймворк `Codeigniter`, в модели есть функция для вывода основного уровня:

```
function menu()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$query = $this->db->get_where('menu',array('parent'=>'none'));
$address = $this->db->query('SELECT address FROM menu');
return $query->result_array();
}
```

в базе в таблице `menu` поля:

```
id title address parent
```

для основных пунктов меню в поле `parent` я прописал `none`, а вот для подпунктов, если подпункт относится к фильмам, то `parent films` и т. д. Скажите правильно ли начал делать и как вывести подменю для каждого основного меню?

Comment: вытащи из таблицы все, потом через рекурсию сделай дерево по parent  оборачивая каждый уровень в '<ul>' и каждая внутренняя подструктура в очередной '<ul>' - получится готовый html, c помощью css попрячь ссылки внутреннего уровня (ul ul {display: none}), с помощью js (можно реализовать и на стороне php) несложно найти в дереве ссылок текущий URL и добавить классы (допустим 'active') самому элементу 'li' и цепочке 'li' элементов выше уровнем, в css открыть 'ul' который находится в активном элементе 'li' (ul .active {display: block}) - все.

можно добавить открывашки/закрывашки субменю - js/css

Comment: в теории то оно просто, а не деле не получается

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, лучше parent сделать числовыми, у вас ведь у каждого поля есть свой ID.

Реализация примерно такая:

Достаешь категории из базы, должно получиться примерно следующее. (Код процедурный, но на ООП практически ничем не отличается)

```
$arr[0] = array(id=>1,title="Категория 1", parent_id="0");
$arr[1] = array(id=>2,title="Категория 2", parent_id="0");
$arr[2] = array(id=>3,title="Категория 3", parent_id="0");

$arr[3] = array(id=>4,title="ПодКатегория 1", parent_id="1");
$arr[4] = array(id=>5,title="ПодКатегория 2", parent_id="2");
$arr[5] = array(id=>6,title="ПодКатегория 3", parent_id="3");
$arr[6] = array(id=>7,title="ПодКатегория 4", parent_id="3");
```

Затем нужно слегка изменить этот массив:

```
$cats = array();
foreach($arr as $item){
    $cats[$item['parent_id']][] = $item;
}
```

Тепрь получилось следующее:

```
$cats[0][0] = array(id=>1,title="Категория 1", parent_id="0");
$cats[0][1] = array(id=>2,title="Категория 2", parent_id="0");
$cats[0][2] = array(id=>3,title="Категория 3", parent_id="0");

    $cats[1][0] = array(id=>4,title="ПодКатегория 1", parent_id="1");
    $cats[2][0] = array(id=>5,title="ПодКатегория 2", parent_id="2");
    $cats[3][0] = array(id=>6,title="ПодКатегория 3", parent_id="3");
    $cats[3][1] = array(id=>7,title="ПодКатегория 4", parent_id="3");
```

Теперь пишем функцию: дерево(Категории, ID родительской категории)

```
function tree($cats,$parent_id){
if(is_array($cats) && isset($cats[$parent_id])){
    $tree = '<ul>';
    foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $item){

    $tree .= '
    <li>
        <a href="category/'.$item['id'].'">
        '.$item['title'].'
        </a>
    </li>';

    $tree .= tree($cats,$item['id']);

}
$tree .= '</ul>';
```

}
    return $tree;
    }

Вывод :

```
echo tree($cats,0);
```

Разберите каждый пункт по отдельности, чтобы понять что к чему. Сложного здесь совсем ничего нет.

P.S. Код писал быстро, не тестировал, так что если где то будет загвостка, пишите я перепроверю.

Comment: еще вопрос по меню. Вот к примеру создал я в админке пункт меню, все нормально. Но вот такой момент, есть адрес site.ru/films/action 
где films это контроллер, а action это метод этого контроллера, который уже отправляет запрос к базе и оттуда вытаскивает нужное. Дак вот если добавить пункт в админке, то как сделать, что бы автоматически появился метод, который будет делать нужную выборку? Ведь не вручную же это все править? Надеюсь понятно изложил вопрос

Comment: Без Вашего кода будет сложно... Я так понимаю "action" это подкатегория films. Нужно написать общий метод, который принимает в качестве параметра подкатегорию. Т.е. $param = 'action'; или $param = 'cartoon'; И опираясь на эти данные делать выборку из базы, примерно так.
function get_method($param){
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM films WHERE category = {$params}';
}

Comment: Сейчас в контроллере films такая картина:

function index()
    {
 $subcat = $this->uri->rsegment(2);
 $this->load->model('films_m');
 $this->data['data'] = $this->films_m->$subcat();
 $this->data['menu'] = $this->menu_m->menu();
 $this->load->view('template_v', $this->data);
    }
при открытии контроллера films вытаскиваются все фильмы.
Далее идут методы под категорий:
function action()
    {
 self::index();
    }

Comment: Вам нужно не метод динамически генерировать, а создать один общий, а в него, динамически передавать параметр. Т.е. не function action(){self::index;}. А что то типа function subcat(action){А здесь уже исходя из переданного параметра(action или triller), производите действия. }

Comment: разобрался! Использовал метод _remap() из Codeigniter которая вызывается по умолчанию. Там в зависимости от сегмента url выполняются те или иные действия. Хотя можно было и самому написать метод, как вы сказали. Я по началу так и хотел, но видимо где то, где то пропустил. А вот если зайти дальше. Создал я пункт меню, к примеру "Программы", должен ведь быть контроллер например "programs". Да к вот тут как можно решить задачу, что бы контроллер создавался? Или как это делается?

Comment: В случае, если Вы добавляете пункт меню... Здесь на сколько я знаю два варианта. 1) Если у Вас каждый контроллер выполняет разные функции, то тут как не крути, придется его ручками писать. 2) А если контроллер programs такой же как и films, не стоит их копировать. В адресной строке передаете что то такое site.com/основной_контроллер/films/action/  или site.com/основной_контроллер/programs/design/.  А в основном контроллере уже реализуете выбор из базы где основная категория например: "программы", а её под категория "дизайн".